# When do we need deep copy in c

Tags: c++, c

In this code:

```
struct test
{
    char *p;
};

struct test glob;
void someFunc(struct test);

int main()
{
    struct test X;
    X.p=malloc(10);
    someFunc(X);

    //free(X.p);  
}


void someFunc(struct test y)
{
    glob.p=y.p;
}
```

In C++ I think this is tricky because when `someFunc` ends, and `y` goes
out of scope - if one has proper destructor and this is a class
object - memory pointed by `y.p` will get freed after `someFunc` ends, and thus `glob.p`
will point to garbage right?

Is this also the case in C considering the same code above? Or will `glob.p` point to usable memory after `someFunc` ends?

Comment: You allocate memory twice - you need to free it twice.

Comment: @PetrBudnik: Ok for second part-btw. I removed that part, since it was basic more or less, and this way to focus only one one question. thanks

Comment: In c++ when you right 'class = value' the class must have the operator= method or it won't compile. Look at the canonical classes. When you write 'class = value' the value is copied, not the pointer. In c when you write 'variable = value' nothing is called. It just assign the value to the variable. In this case the pointer. If you free the pointer the content won't exist any more.

Comment: @nsvir: I am interested how it goes in c..; ps you can see I am not freeing anything in my code, so how does it happen as it is shown in my code?

Comment: @dmcr_code There is no destructors in `C`. `glob.p` will be pointing to a valid memory until you free that memory (using any pointer pointing to that memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, after `someFunc()` ends, `y` is destroyed, but not what `y.p` points to. You can keep using the memory you allocated wherever you want until you call `free()` - that's one of the advantages of dynamic allocation (and one of its drawbacks too - with great power comes great responsibility.)

In C++, the same thing will happen, unless there's a destructor that deletes the pointer. In that case, yes, both `glob.p` and `X.p` would be invalid pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ this same code will work the same as in C. Both should be fine as you pass the pointer around. You just need to be aware who owns that and thus deletes it.

If you write a destructor as you said, you should usually also provide proper copy and assignment operators. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) to prevent things like invalid pointers.

If you don't then, yes, such code will be dangerous and you need to be very much aware of what you are doing (and especially why this way).

Answer (score 0):

After `someFunc` ends, `glob.p` will point to the memory allocated with your call to `malloc` in `main`.  This is true whether this is compiled as a C or C++ program (with `struct` removed from the `someFunc` declaration in the c++ case).  If `test` has a different definition as a c++ class, as you seem to be asking at the end, then what happens at the end of `someFunc` depends entirely on the particulars of this definition.